# MySQL: Increase AUTO_INCREMENT by a fixed value ONCE

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm trying to update several tables existing primary keys (a 1000 shift).  I know I can get the ID with the following:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$database' AND TABLE_NAME = '$table'
```

Then I can update like so:

```
ALTER TABLE $table AUTO_INCREMENT = $old_ai_value+1000
```

But is there a better, shorter way?  I guessed at

```
ALTER TABLE $table AUTO_INCREMENT = AUTO_INCREMENT+1000
```

But that only gives an error.

Comment: Whats the error it gives you?

Comment: what are you trying to do here? adjusting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field changes the value for the next inserted value, it doesn't affect existing rows

Comment: The error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT+1000' at line 1`  @pala_ What I'm trying to do is create a 1000 row buffer for test data to be entered at fixed ID locations.

Comment: @bing okay just making sure you weren't under the impression this was going to change existing rows - i sort of got that impression when you said 'update existing primary keys'

Comment: @pala_ Yeah, what I meant was: if someone has entered 3 people (keys 1, 2, 3) I want to up those to 1001, 1002, 1003 so test data can enter in the 1-1000 range and hard-coded references can be made.  I already know the code I presented works, I was just looking for a better/faster way.

Comment: and these ids are not a foreign key on another table anywhere?

Comment: No, they are not.  That would give a foreign key error, not a syntax error.  You're welcome to build a quick MySQL table and try it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do two queries from PHP. First get the old `AUTO_INCREMENT` value using the `SELECT` query that you showed. Add 1000 to it in PHP, then use that as the value in an `ALTER TABLE` query.

You can't do it entirely in SQL because the `AUTO_INCREMENT =` parameter in `ALTER TABLE` is not evaluated as an expression, it has to be a literal integer.

If you're trying to update the IDs of existing rows, not set the ID used for new rows, you can do:

```
UPDATE $table
SET id = id + 1000
```

However, this will also update the auto increment, so future rows will get IDs above 1000, they won't fill in the gap. Auto increment is always supposed to be higher than any of the existing IDs.